# percentage value in ampiechart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

In AmChart, can I get values next to pie chart without the percentage value and symbol?

Here is the pie chart I am referring to.[Source:](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/pie-chart-with-legend/)

I want to display `(For Czech Republic) 256.9` in the Pie Chart and not `31.06%`. Same for others as well.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see   [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3CLY/)

i have just edited this `"labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]",`

i hope this would help you